# Does quasi-coherent modules over $(X^{\text{an}},\mathcal{O}_{X^{\text{an}}})$ have enough injectives?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

We know that for any scheme $X$, the category of quasi-coherent modules over $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ has enough injectives. Now let us consider a smooth complex variety $X$. Then we can use GAGA to get a complex manifold $X^{\text{an}}$ together with the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{X^{\text{an}}}$.

> I wonder whether the category of quasi-coherent modules over the (locally) ringed space $(X^{\text{an}},\mathcal{O}_{X^{\text{an}}})$ has enough injectives.

In general, it can not be observed from GAGA because we only have the correspondence for coherent modules. One motivation is to see if we can do Fourier-Mukai transformations to the associated analytic spaces via the GAGA (some derived functors can not be defined directly in $\textbf{Coh}(X)$ because it rarely has enough injectives).

Comment: What is a quasicoherent sheaf on a complex analytic space?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger one definition is given in Tag [01BD](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01BD), but maybe it's not the right one. These things exist separately from the language of schemes!

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn In the Tag that you referred to, it says that quasicoherent sheaves over a ringed space might not form an abelian category, and in particular, I tend to believe that this issue appears even for $\mathbb C^n$. Liquid modules give rise to a correct concept of quasicoherent sheaves.

Comment: Regarding your motivation: there should be no problem making sense of Fourier-Mukai in the analytic setting by working in the derived  category of **all** $\mathcal{O}_{X^{an}}$-modules with bounded coherent cohomology.

Comment: @DonuArapura Do we have the equivalence $D^b(\textbf{Coh}(X^{an}))\cong D^b_{\text{coh}}(\textbf{Mod}(X^{an}))$ in general?

Comment: In p.7823 of THE DOLBEAULT DGA OF A FORMAL NEIGHBORHOOD by Shilin Yu, it writes that the equivalence $D^b(Coh(X))\to D^b_{coh}(Mod(X))$ is unknown for general complex spaces.